# Unity 2D Top Down Collisions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

My Unity project is a 2D Tron kind of like game, where the character moves around at a constant velocity and changes direction to up, down, left, and right while leaving a line in its path. All that is working fine. But I want to be able to collide with them as well as with the walls around the map. I want to achieve this using raycasting collisions. Basically, I want the character to not be able to move towards the direction it was moving if a wall is in front of it. The thing is that I don't really know how to stop the character when this happens.

An example of what I want is this:

[image]

Here is my code for the player.

```
void Start(){
    direction = Vector2.down;
}

void Update(){
    Move(up, down, left, right);
    Collision();
}

void Move(KeyCode up, KeyCode down, KeyCode left, KeyCode right){
    position = transform.position;
    direction = (Input.GetKeyDown(up) && direction != Vector2.down)?Vector2.up:direction;
    direction = (Input.GetKeyDown(down) && direction != Vector2.up)?Vector2.down:direction;
    direction = (Input.GetKeyDown(left) && direction != Vector2.right)?Vector2.left:direction;
    direction = (Input.GetKeyDown(right) && direction != Vector2.left)?Vector2.right:direction;
    speed = (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))?2: 4;
    velocity = direction / speed;
    position += velocity;
    transform.position = position;
    Trail trail = Instantiate(trail1, transform.position, Quaternion.identity) as Trail;
    trail.color = (speed == 2)?new Color32(247, 118, 34, 255):new Color32(254, 174, 52, 255);
}

void Collision(){
    float rayLength = 10;
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, direction, rayLength, collisionMask);
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direction * rayLength, Color.red);
    if(hit){

    }
}
```

So far, this draws a ray into the direction the player is moving towards. To put everything into perspective, lets say the player is moving left at a constant speed, and I am not pressing the key. If a wall is in front of the player, it will not be able to go through the wall.

Comment: This might give you some ideas : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/593293/how-to-add-a-collider-to-a-trail-renderer.html

Comment: I already did the tail, they are square prefabs with colliders, I would just like to make the character collide with them and the walls through raycasting if possible.

Comment: Read the link I've sent you again, there are multiples possible approaches about colliding with trails in it.